# Not sending sms on loop with cordova plugin

Tags: angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework, cordova-plugins

I am trying to send sms on loop with Cordova plugin.
The issue that big part of SMS not sent. 
Dose cordova have some limitation or should I do some ideal time?
this my code:

```
var contactsLen = $scope.contacts.length;
    for (var i = 0; i < contactsLen; i++) {
      if ($scope.contacts[i].hasOwnProperty('number')) {
        $cordovaSms
          .send($scope.contacts[i].number, text)
          .then(function () {
            if (i == contactsLen - 1) {
              $scope.log += 'send All!'
            }
          }, function (error) {
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The plugin code that sends the SMS is asynchronous, which means running it in a loop like that will not work the way you expect. If you want to fire multiple async events and wait for them *all* to finish, then you need to use something like q$ (https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q) to handle it. Make note of the all() method which lets you pass an array of promises.